# hide component in Angular in certain dynamic route

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-components, angular-activatedroute

I need to hide certain components from my main home page like the navbar and footer when I'm logged in to my admin panel. My admin components are lazy-loaded based on an admin module when called. The necessary components are getting hidden as expected when on admin view if the routes are not dynamic i.e like `/admin/login`, `/admin/dashboard` etc. But the problem starts if the routes are dynamic like `/admin/category/:categoryId` or `/admin/user/:userId` and in these routes the necessary components like navbar and footer doesn't hide itself. I'm getting the dynamic ids for the routes using `ActivatedRoute` in the necessary components. Below is the method I'm using on my main page to read the application routes and show/hide components accordingly.

Main.ts

```
 import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

  public url: any;

  constructor(private router: Router) {

    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.url = event.url;
      }
    })
  }
```

Main.html

```
<div class="main__container">
  <app-navbar
    *ngIf="url !== '/admin' && url !== '/admin/dashboard' && url !== '/admin/post-article' && url !== '/admin/video' && url !== '/admin/login' && url !== '/admin/sign-up' && url !== '/admin/category/:categoryId'">
  </app-navbar>
  <app-footer
    *ngIf="url !== '/admin' && url !== '/admin/dashboard' && url !== '/admin/category/:categoryId' && url !== '/admin/post-article' && url !== '/admin/video' && url !== '/admin/login' && url !== '/admin/sign-up'">
  </app-footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using regex pattern to match patterns to determine whether to hide or show routes OR Use a service that holds information to determine hiding/showing and subscribe to them in every component that needs this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is to define regular expressions and test against those.
Or maybe it's enough for you to check the `string#includes(string)` function. I would also suggest to use a more *reactive* (rxjs like) approach.

On my template I would have:

```html
<div class="main__container">
  <app-navbar *ngIf="canShowNavBar$ | async">
  </app-navbar>
  <app-footer *ngIf="canShowFooter$ | async">
  </app-footer>
</div>
```

Where on the typescript file I would have:

```js
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

   canShowNavBar$: Observable<boolean>;
   canShowFooter$: Observable<boolean>;
   navigationEvents$: Observable<NavigationEnd>;


   constructor(private router: Router){}

   ngOnInit() {
     // Like this we define the stream of the NavigationEnd events
     this.navigationEvents$ = this.router.events.pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        // This one is not really needed but we're giving some hints to the typescript compiler
        map(event => event as NavigationEnd) 
      );
      // Here we define the stream of booleans that determine whether to show the component or not on your template.
      this.canShowNavBar$ = this.navigationEvents$.pipe(
         map(event => this.shouldShowNavBar(event.url))
      );
      // Because actually you check for the same conditions
      this.canShowFooter$ = this.canShowNavBar$;
   }

   shouldShowNavBar(url: string): boolean {
      // And here you should test against regular expressions:
     switch(true) {
        case /\/admin\/dashboard/.test(url):
        case /\/admin\/category/.test(url):
        // More cases where you should show the navBar
           return true;
        default: return false;
     }



   }
   
}
```

You can read more about [Regular Expressions on JavaScript here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Another approach of implementing the `shouldShowNavBar` would be using some array predicates like `some`: Like so:

```js
shouldShowNavBar(url: string): boolean {
   const conditions = [
      !url.startsWith('/admin/dashboard'),
      !url.includes('/admin/category'),
      // More conditions?
   ];
   return conditions.some(isTrue => isTrue);
}
```

#### If you don't want to use the async keep your code as it was but do:

```html
<div class="main__container">
  <app-navbar *ngIf="shouldDisplayNavBar(url)">
  </app-navbar>
  <app-footer *ngIf="shouldDisplayNavBar(url)">
  </app-footer>
</div>
```

```js
shouldShowNavBar(url: string): boolean {
   if(!url) {
     return false;
   }

   const conditions = [
      !url.startsWith('/admin/dashboard'),
      !url.includes('/admin/category'),
      // More conditions?
   ];
   return conditions.some(isTrue => isTrue);
}
```

Comment: is there a way I can use just shouldShowNavBar(url) method and exclude the async functions? if so how can I call it in my template with *ngIf and how to catch the current url in my ngOnInit()

Comment: Technically you shoud be able to call

```<div *ngIf="shouldShowNavBar(url)">``` with the current setup you had

Comment: in doing so it's returning Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined. It seems url.includes/startsWith is coming as undefined

Comment: because there's a moment where the `url` is not set yet because the subscribe callback hasnt been activated yet.

You should add this at the beggining of the function

```if(!url) return false;```

Comment: Or initialise the `url` property with some value that makes sense to you

Comment: inside which function should I be adding `if(!url) return false;` Please give a bit more info because using async becomes a bit complicated for me

Comment: the approach is working when there is just condition inside the [ ] . Adding multiple URL like `!url.include('/admin/dashboard'), !url.incude('/admin/category/:categoryId'),` is not working

Comment: change `some` for `every` if you want to do an AND with all the conditions. Do `some` if you want an OR

Comment: I get you..but the actual problem still remains for dynamic routes such as `/admin/category/:categoryId`

Comment: Your dynamic routes will all start with `/admin/category` and then will follow up with `/123` or whatever ID. So with those you can just do `url.startsWith('/admin/category')` and you will match all of the paths that start with `/admin/category`. If you have some complex URL I suggest using regular expressions which you have some examples with my code and you also have the link to the documentation on how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  /**
   * Check if the router url contains the specified route
   *
   * @param {string} route
   * @returns
   * @memberof MyComponent
   */
  hasRoute(route: string) {
    return this.router.url.includes(route);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- First view -->
<div *ngIf="hasRoute('home')">
    First View
</div>

<!-- Second view activated when the route doesn't contain the home route -->
<div *ngIf="!hasRoute('home')">
    Second View
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide explanation for your answers, so others can benefit from it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).